# Bitcoin disappeared after resetting the blockchain and transactions

Tags: wallet-recovery

I'm looking for some advice on trying to recover bitcoins. 
I transferred some bitcoin to my multibit wallet, it came through but still didn't confirm after 20 hours. So I tried resetting the blockchain and transactions, and now my wallet is empty! I got the message

```
com.google.bitcoin.store.BlockStoreException: Corrupted block store: could not find chain head
```

I searched for this and found advice about deleting the.spvchain file, but I don't appear to have this file!

Edit: Ok, so I just downloaded the newest version of multibit and the bitcoins appeared. All is good! Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4):

Your wallet shows empty because it doesn't really "know" that one or more addresses that it controls "owns" some bitcoins because you manually deleted the blockchain files.

It will display your correct balance once it synchronizes again, provided of course that you have not deleted the `.wallet` file.

I would also suggest you take extra care when deleting the `.spvchain` file, more at: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bitcoinj/vIbsMfd1NUA

Another approach would be to [export your private key(s) for non-zero addresses](https://multibit.org/help_exportingPrivateKeys.html) and import them to a clean installation. Make sure you keep a back-up of your `.wallet` file somewhere safe throughout this process.

Comment: Op, you can choose @George's answer or decide to use your own answer but please detail the circumstances for the next person encountering this issue! Thx